# How to install ungoogled-chromium in Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, chromium, build

How can I install [ungoogled-chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) on my Debian Jessie? I think I have to build it manually, there's no simple way (yet)? They have "Building" page, but it's not really clear what I should do.

This is what I've tried:

We need `Python 3` and `Python 2` and `Ninja` to use `buildlib`, to install `ungoogled-chromium`:

```
user@debian:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2

user@debian:~$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.9

user@debian:~$ apt-get install ninja-build
```

Because we are using Debian Jessie, we need to do extra steps:

*"Note for Debian Jessie users: ungoogled-chromium is configured to build against the system's FFmpeg (available in Stretch and onwards); Libav (used in Jessie) will not work. However, FFmpeg is available in jessie-backports. To install it, add jessie-backports to the apt sources, and then install libavutil-dev, libavcodec-dev, and libavformat-dev from it. Note that this will replace Libav."*

Okay, let's add `jessie-backports` to our `sources.list`:

- Open and edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- Add this to the file `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main`
- Save and exit
- Update and upgrade: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Now we need to install the `libavutil-dev`, `libavcodec-dev`, and `libavformat-dev` packages:

- `sudo apt-get install libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev`

Let's download the `ungoogled-chromium`:

- `wget https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium/archive/master.zip`
- `unzip master.zip`
- `cd ungoogled-chromium-master`

Okay, we have everything ready to go. Now we need to "invoke"(?) the `build.py` to install the `ungoogled-chromium`:

- `chmod +x build.py`
- `./build.py`

This is as far as I can go. `build.py` [throws me an error and the building will fail](http://pastebin.com/p5mHDjR5).

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/ suggests you should try using Python 3.5 instead of 3.4

Answer (score 2):

They provide pre-built binaries at https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/. Since they only provide packages for Debian stretch, you can use the "Semi-statically-linked Linux build".